# Setting the width of Kendo UI Grid Popup (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using the MVC Wrappers of Kendo UI and I cannot set the width of the popup. I've tried two methods and none are working. Here's what I've tried:

```
.Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup)
    .TemplateName("Create")
    .Window(w => w.Title("Add Interruption")
        .Name("addInterruption")
        .Width(700)))
```

and

```
.Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup)
    .TemplateName("Create")
    .Window(w => w.Title("Add Interruption")
        .Name("addInterruption")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:700px;" })))
```

Height doesn't work either.

How do you set the width of the popup window?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
For anyone else struggling with this, here's the fix:

```
.k-edit-form-container { width: auto;}
```

This is found in the kendo.common.min.css file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly the Settings  you applied in both of your snippets are not serialized and not applied to the window at all when using Ajax binding (not even sure about Server Binding).

Basically to set the Width I suggest you to use the following JavaScript when the page has loaded:

```
$("#NameOfTheGrid").data().kendoGrid.options.editable.window.width = "1000px";
```

Comment: Appreciate the assistance! Wish they would make an update as I'm sure many people are screaming for this.

Comment: Please add me to the 'SCREAMING' crowd. Have been a Telerik MVC user from the start and a bit disheartened by the lack of work happening on Kendo UI MVC front.

Answer (score 7):

For me,

```
    .k-edit-form-container { width: auto;}
```

was needed when binding in server mode. I just added it as a style in the view instead of editing the kendo css file.

The other answer,

```
$("#NameOfTheGrid").data().kendoGrid.options.editable.window.width = "1000px";
```

worked great with ajax binding but not with server binding.

Comment: .k-edit-form-container { width: auto;}
was key for me, otherwise it was just widening the screen and still breaking my long text. Thanks boss!